# Hudson maven test after deployment done

Tags: maven, hudson

I have configured Hudson for continuous integration. in my Maven job I have define  "Deploy war/ear to a container " option and " M2 Extra Build Steps -post". in "M2 Extra Build Steps -post" I have define run to test case. But before deployment complete maven test will run.

Is there any way to configure run the test cases after deployment completed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter -Dmaven.test.skip=true or -DskipTests=true in MAVEN_OPTS (this is present Jenkins clicking the Advanced button), depending on whether you want to skip test compilation and execution or only execution.